# Getting error The method sort(List<T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List<LinkedInUser>)

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

@Test

```
public void sortingTest() throws LinkedInException {

LinkedInUser Han = new LinkedInUser("Han", "hanpass");

LinkedInUser LUKE = new LinkedInUser("LUKE", "LUKEpass");

LinkedInUser leia = new LinkedInUser("leia", "leiapass");

Han.addConnection(LUKE);

Han.addConnection(leia);

List<LinkedInUser> hansConnections = Han.getConnections();


Collections.sort(hansConnections);

hansConnections.get(0).equals(leia);

hansConnections.get(1).equals(LUKE);

}
```

I am getting an error code with my sort, if anyone could provide insight as to how to fix this issue I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

The [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-) is declared as:

```java
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)
```

When you call with a `List<LinkedInUser>`, it means that `T` is a `LinkedInUser`, which means that **`LinkedInUser` *must* implement `Comparable<LinkedInUser>`** *(or some super-type of `LinkedInUser`)*.

If you can't do that, call the [overload](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-), so you can supply a `Comparator` instead:

```java
public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

Right now, without the class implementing `Comparable`, and without supplying a `Comparator`, what order did you expect the objects to be sorted in?

Answer (score 2):

You need to read this documentation of [Java Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html). Find the sort method and check how it works.

You can do two things:

1. Implement `Comparable` interface in your `LinkedinUser` class and override `compareTo` method, providing its implementation according to which you want to sort objects.
2. Use `Comparator` interface, and implementing the `compare` method(using Anonymous Interface Implementations)